# How to draw a violin plot with the color showing the expression of gene value?

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

I am trying to plot the gene expression of "gene A" among several groups. 
I use ggplot2 to draw, but I fail

```
p <- ggplot(MAPK_plot, aes(x = group, y = gene_A)) + geom_violin(trim = FALSE , aes( colour = gene_A))  + theme_classic()
```

And I want to get the figure like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3kbz.png) from https://www.researchgate.net/publication/313728883_Neuropilin-1_Is_Expressed_on_Lymphoid_Tissue_Residing_LTi-like_Group_3_Innate_Lymphoid_Cells_and_Associated_with_Ectopic_Lymphoid_Aggregates

Comment: Hello [陈海填](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8729894/陈海填), welcome to SO. Please take a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), to modify your question, with a smaller sample taken from your data (check?dput()). Posting images of your data or no data makes it difficult to impossible for us to help you!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to provide data to get a more specific answer, tailored to your problem. But, I do not want that you get demotivated by the down-votes you got so far and, based on your link, maybe this example can give you some food for thought.

Nice job on figuring out that you have to use `geom_violin`. Further, you will need some form of faceting / multi-panels. Finally, to do the full annotation like in the given link, you need to make use of the `grid` package functionality (which I do not use here).

I am not familiar with gene-expression data sets, but I use a IMDB movie rating data set for this example (stored in the package ggplot2movies).

```
library(ggplot2)

library(ggplot2movies)
library(data.table)
mv <- copy(movies)
setDT(mv)
# make some variables for our plotting example
mv[, year_10 := cut_width(year, 10)]
mv[, rating_10yr_avg := mean(rating), by = year_10]
mv[, length_3gr := cut_number(length, 3)]

ggplot(mv, 
       aes(x = year_10, 
           y = rating)) + 
  geom_violin(aes(fill = rating_10yr_avg),
              scale = "width") +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(length_3gr))
```

[image]

Please do not take this answer as a form on encouragement of not posting data relevant to your problem.